# how to rectreate this dynamic controls

Tags: asp.net

try to make a simple application in which I have a dropdown list with tems - numbers from 1 to 4.

Depending on the number the user choose - I create dynamically this number of checkboxes with binded checkedchanged event. So when the user checks some of the checkboxes so checkedchanged event is raised and I store the text of the checked checkbox in session and then when I click a button I want to see the text only from the checked checkboxes.

But it seems that in the checkedchanged event handler I should recreate the dynamic cotrol but I haven't found a solution. Thank you in advance.

```
public partial class proba : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dd1.Items.Add("1");
        dd1.Items.Add("2");
        dd1.Items.Add("3");
        dd1.Items.Add("4");
}

protected void dd1_SelectedIndexChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int numTourists = Convert.ToInt32(dd1.SelectedItem.Text);

    for (int i = 0; i < numTourists; i++)
    {
        CheckBox chk = new CheckBox();
        chk.ID = "chk" + i;
        chk.Text = "box" + i;

         chk.AutoPostBack = true;

        chk.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(checkChanged);
        Page.FindControl("form1").Controls.Add(chk);


    }
}

protected void checkChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     // here I should recteate the control

    CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)sender;

    lblpr.Text += chk.Text;

    Srolession["chk"] = chk.Text;


}
```

Comment: no you have to create at page load event

Comment: and can you post some simple code

Comment: i posted an answer ...see it for refrence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     static bool chkddlchange=false; //define this....to check you Drop Changed Or Not.
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dd1.Items.Add("1");
            dd1.Items.Add("2");
            dd1.Items.Add("3");
            dd1.Items.Add("4");
    if(Page.IsPostBack && chkddl==true)
    {
     int numTourists = Convert.ToInt32(dd1.SelectedItem.Text);
       chkddl=true;//make true so you can know that you ddlindex is changed..
        for (int i = 0; i < numTourists; i++)
        {
            CheckBox chk = new CheckBox();
            chk.ID = "chk" + i;
            chk.Text = "box" + i;

             chk.AutoPostBack = true;

            chk.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(checkChanged);
            Page.FindControl("form1").Controls.Add(chk);


        }
    }
    }

    protected void dd1_SelectedIndexChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int numTourists = Convert.ToInt32(dd1.SelectedItem.Text);
       chkddl=true;//make true so you can know that you ddlindex is changed..you have to 
checkboxex on page load
        for (int i = 0; i < numTourists; i++)
        {
            CheckBox chk = new CheckBox();
            chk.ID = "chk" + i;
            chk.Text = "box" + i;

             chk.AutoPostBack = true;

            chk.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(checkChanged);
            Page.FindControl("form1").Controls.Add(chk);


        }
    }
```